# Angular selector is not a known element: if it's an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, ivy

I created a component and tried to use it in another component by declaring a selector in the display part.

```
<app-component1></app-component1>
```

But I get a compile error. I checked the imports in the modules, everything is fine, there are no errors. Can't figure out what is the reason why I can't use the component?
Here is stackblitz example of my app.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uve2pn?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the module that you import doesn't have an export for component that you are looking for?

When you e.g have a component let's say ComponentA in ModuleA, to use ComponentA in other ModuleB, you need to have in Modul A

```
declarations: [ComponentA]
exports: [ComponentA]
```

Comment: I have fixed your code, you had a circular dependency between AppModule and Page1Module, make sure you import your modules only when necessary without additional dependencies, for the best solution use lazyLoading routes - https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code by converting modules to regular components and declaring them in blocks "declarations" and "exports" in app.module